# Sencha touch 2.4.1 - localstorage using own ID

Tags: extjs, local-storage

I am trying to save data to local storage and I want to use my own ID.
But new id is generated.. and not using my ID.

My model:

```
Ext.define('mOQOLD.model.ActivityList',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Model',
    config:{
        dProperty : 'uniqueid', // dummy name(not a field)
        clientIdProperty : 'ID',
        identifier: {
            type: 'simple'
            },
        fields: [
            { name: "ID", type: "auto" },
            { name: "activityID", type: "int" },
            { name: "newRandom", type: "float" },
            { name: "rTime", type: "date", dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i:s" }
        ]
    }
});
```

My store:

```
Ext.define('mOQOLD.store.ActivityListStoreOffline',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    requires:["mOQOLD.model.ActivityList",
                 'Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage'],

    config:{
        storeId:"ActivityListStoreOffline",
        model:"mOQOLD.model.ActivityList",
        grouper: {
            groupFn: function(rec) {
                var date = rec.get("actDtlStime");
                return Ext.Date.format(date, "h a");
            }
        }, 
        autoLoad:false,
        sorters: [
                    { property: "actDtlStime", direction: "ASC" }
                ],

        proxy   : {
            type    : 'localstorage',
            id      : "ActivityListStoreOffline",
            model   : "mOQOLD.model.ActivityList",
            reader: {
                type: "json"
            }
        }
    }

})
```

The result( chrome) :

> key : ActivityListStoreOffline-ext-record-19
>   value:
>   {"ID":"153",15:13:00","activityID":111,"newRandom":null,"rTime":"2015-05-26 19:31:51","id":"ext-record-19"}

What I expect:

> key : ActivityListStoreOffline-153
>   value:
>   {"ID":"153",15:13:00","activityID":111,"newRandom":null,"rTime":"2015-05-26 19:31:51"}  no id generated!!!

Thanks in advance..

Comment: When you create the model instance, are you setting the ID?

Comment: Yes... in load function, I copy from online store to offline store.......

this.each(function(item,index,length){
           } else {
         var newItem=item.copy();
         offlineStore.add(newItem);
         offlineStore.sync();
               }
           

       });

Answer (score 0):

There are two places you can set the ID:
In the model(http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-idProperty)
and in the reader (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Reader-cfg-idProperty)

Both places use the "idProperty" attribute. Which defaults to lowercase 'id'.

For example, change your reader to:

```
proxy   : {
        type    : 'localstorage',
        id      : "ActivityListStoreOffline",
        model   : "mOQOLD.model.ActivityList",
        reader: {
            type: "json",
            idProperty: "ID",
        }
    }
```